# Create dynamic id and link them

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using a bootstrap's component, collapse. Using a ngFor, I'm trying to generate a dynamic id and link it.

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I want to set:

`<a href="#collapse{{i}}">....`
`<div id="colapse{{i}}">...`

If someone could give me any tip I would appreciate it.

Comment: I would recommend looking into the Angular integrations with Bootstrap rather than trying to re-write the Bootstrap mechanisms. I use ng-bootstrap, and I see a lot of people using ngx-bootstrap. There are several others you can look at too.

Comment: Also, you've not added `*ngFor` to your example, and you've not indicated which element should have a dynamic id in the main example

Comment: I've indicated below *(So, I want to set:), ngFor="let item of lines;let i = index";

Comment: You've just said that you want to use `ngFor` - not *where* it will be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generete an dynamic id you can do this:

In **html**:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of element;let index=index">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="{{cssClassByIndex(index)}}" role="button"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Link with href
    </a>

    .
    .
    .
    <div class="collapse" id="{{cssClassByIndex(index)}}">
        <div class="card card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim
            keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nel **.ts**

```
cssClassByIndex(index:number) {
 return 'collapse'+index;
}
```

Practically you can implement a method that make the concatenation of 'collapse'  with  index, e call it with interpolation in the html

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use this syntax, the following will work as expected:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of element;let index=index">
    <a href="{{'#tab_' + your expression here}}"></a>
</div>
```

You can also bind using the attr prefix like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of element;let index=index">
    <a [attr.href]="'#tab_' + your expression here"></a>
</div>
```